# How would I pass some data from a mongo db to a service before load time?

Tags: nestjs

I currently access a mongo db and it's collections in a service like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

  constructor(@InjectModel('Cats') private categoriesModel: Model<CategoriesDocument>) {}

  private categories: Category[] = categories;
...
```

Then with in a method I can call that

```
this.categoriesModel
```

All this works and I'm able to retrieve data.  My question is, is there away to retrieve the data from a mongo db BEFORE my service is fired up?  In example
products.module.ts

```
// do the mongoose call here as an async / await method.  Then have it pass the data into my provider as a class BEFORE it fires up?

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Cats', schema: CategoriesSchema }])],
  providers: [CategoriesResolver, CategoriesService],
})
export class CategoriesModule {}
```

Comment: What about using [`onModuleInit`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events#lifecycle-events-1)?

Comment: A constructor __must__ be called to create an instance of a class. The `onModuleInit` is an instance method. Therefore, the constructor must be called before `onModuleInit` can be

Comment: I also see the asynchronous example in documentation I hadn't seen it.  Thank you!  @JayMcDoniel